# Как можно это ограничить?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

У меня есть код ,который анимирует полосы вокруг тега `, только эти полосы уходят в разные стороны.

[image: Он уходит вот так]

Уходит вот так , а надо что бы он крутился по бордеру тега `a`, как это можно исправить?

```css
.learn-more {
  color: white;
  animation: learn 8s;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 600 18px Consolas;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.learn-more span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, white);
  animation: animate1 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.learn-more span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white);
  animation: animate2 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

.learn-more span:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black, white);
  animation: animate3 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.learn-more span:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
  animation: animate4 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="learn-more" href="about.html">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  Learn more!
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте к `.learn-more` добавить:

```
display: inline-block; 
overflow: hidden;
```

`overflow` не работает на строчных элементах, поэтому делаем ссылку не строчной (в данном случае inline-block)